# Automatically switch the background

Tags: android, background-image

How to automatically switch the background

in layout

```
android:background="@drawable/image">
```

I have two pictures
I want to allow automatic switching

Comment: use `layout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable)`

Comment: it must be on some event and not automatically.

Comment: imran khan please make a examples

Comment: @凱文 鄭 : post your code then i will edit

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/images1"
    >

Comment: thanks friend.+1 for new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way :

```
public class mainActivity extends Activity 
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            Resources res = getResources(); //resource handle
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.images1); //new Image that was added to the res folder
        LinearLayout linearLayout =   (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.etxtLayout); 
        linearLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTask  = new TimerTask() {
@Override
public void run() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if(loadFirst){
loadFirst = false;
layout_reference.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagename1);
}else{
loadFirst = true;
layout_reference.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagename2);
}
}
};
timer.schedule(timerTask,0,10000);//fires every 10secs
```

try this code in code and also declare a boolean variable "boolean loadFirst = false" in your oncreate method()

Answer (score 0):

Create a thread and assign the time of sleep and put the the layout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable) with sleep method and can use  a flag variable to switch between both the background drawables, if 1 set 2 and if 2 set 1.

or you can put the layout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable) code into runOnUIThread.